# Use different stylesheet for PHP include

Tags: php, html, css

The php page consists of

```
<header>


<?php include('mid content'); ?>


<footer>
```

The `header` and `footer` has same css file where as `mid content` has different css file.

I tried this:

```
<?php include('midcontent.php'); ?>
<style>
<?php include 'CSS/another_css.css'; ?>
</style>
```

But in this case the `footer` gets overridden with the `another_css` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how CSS works. Any CSS file loaded in a page is applied to every element on the page. If you don't want your `another_css.css` file affecting the footer, make its rules specific to the elements you want to affect.

i.e.

```
<div id="midContent"><?php include('midcontent.php'); ?></div>
<style>
#midContent a { color: pink; }
</style>
```